# MockMvc expected Entity{field, field} but obtained {field, field}

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, mockmvc

i'm making a test of a Client, specifically i'm getting all clients, and i have this piece of code:

```
ClientMockMvc.perform(get("/clients?sort=id,desc"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].location").value(DEFAULT_LOCATION))
```

But i got this error:

Expected: Location{id=974351, street='AAAAA', number='AAAA', province={id= 974251, desc="AAAA"}}

Actual: {id=974351, street='AAAAA', number='AAAA', province={id= 974251, desc="AAAA"}}

I can't find a workaround for this, anyone has an idea? Am i doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is DEFAULT_LOCATION defined?

Comment: In the test, i gave it default values, asigned it to the client and persisted it in the database.

Comment: show how it is declared? As a String? or Object?

Comment: DEFAULT_LOCATION = new Location()
            .street(DEFAULT_STREET)
            .number(DEFAULT_NUMBER)
            .province(DEFAULT_PROVINCE);

        DEFAULT_LOCATION = locationRepository.save(DEFAULT_LOCATION);

Comment: see DEFAULT_LOCATION you are creating a new object hence the error is it is expecting `Location{id=974351, street='AAAAA', number='AAAA', province={id= 974251, desc="AAAA"}}`. But `jsonPath("$.[*].location"` is a string which is `{id=974351, street='AAAAA', number='AAAA', province={id= 974251, desc="AAAA"}}` without Location prefix

Comment: How could i fix it? I guess DEFAULT_LOCATION.toString() Wont help right?

Comment: what does this endpoint return `/clients?sort=id,desc`

Comment: It returns the list of all clients